# Plot equal-spaced points within a square (n x n)

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, matlab-figure

How could I plot equally spaced points in square in matlab. As shown below

```
                          . . . .
                          . . . .
                          . . . .
                          . . . .
```

The figure below is for a 4x4 dimension square. I would like to reference each point and store in a variable [Point(i).xcord, Point(i).ycord] and plot as shown below:

```
For i=1:1:16
Point(i).xcord = <What expression goes here>
Point(i).ycord = <what expression goes here>
plot(Point(i).xcord, Point(i).ycord)
```

In order to get an output in grid form as shown above, could anyone explain a simple way of doing this.

Comment: Please do not add back tags that have been removed without a good reason. This question has nothing to do with deployment or sparse matrices (please read tag descriptions before using them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ndgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) as follows:

```
N = 4; % Square size
[xcord, ycord] = ndgrid(1:N); % generate all combinations. Gives two matrices
plot(xcord(:), ycord(:), '.') % plot all points at once
axis([0 N+1 0 N+1]) % set axis limits
axis square % make actual sizes of both axes equal
```

`xcord`, `ycord` are matrices that contain the coordinates of the points. This is faster than using a struct array as in your code. You can index them such as `xcord(2,3)`.

If you need to convert to a struct array, use

```
Point = struct('xcord', num2cell(xcord(:)), 'ycord', num2cell(ycord(:)));
```

Comment: It works! Please, What could it be like using a struct as shown in the question? In several wsn protocols, sensor nodes are referenced that way. Thanks Luis!

Comment: @Abdulhameed I've added a line to do the conversion, please see edited answer